# How to get devcards working with shadow-cljs

Tags: fulcro

My devcards used to work with Figwheel. However I can't get them to display with shadow-cljs.

Shadow emits this message:

> shadow-cljs - HTTP server for :cards available at http://localhost:3450

The namespace `cards.card-ui` is just a series of requires.

I have a `println` message in `cards.card-ui` that is being displayed.

In `shadow-cljs.edn` I have two `:builds`. This is the second one:

```
      :cards {:target           :browser
              :output-dir       "resources/public/js/cards"
              :asset-path       "js/cards"
              :modules          {:main {:entries [cards.card-ui]}}
              :compiler-options {:static-fns false}
              :devtools         {:http-root          "resources/public"
                                 :http-resource-root "resources/public"
                                 :http-port          3450
                                 :http-handler       shadow.http.push-state/handle
                                 :push-state/index   "cards.html"
                                 :preloads           [devtools.preload
                                                      default-db-format.preload]}
              :dev              {:compiler-options {:devcards true}}
              }
```

`cards.html` has a body tag that has a div tag that has id "app". I take the browser to `http://localhost:3450/cards.html` and just get a blank page. My best theory is that the `cards.card-ui` namespace is not being mounted at `app`.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the only way to get an example Fulcro application that uses shadow-cljs rather than Figwheel is via the lein template. So at the command prompt:

```
lein new fulcro app shadow-cljs
```

Here `app` is any name you choose and `shadow-cljs` is an option. After studying the resultant application I realised that the namespace `cards.card-ui` should not just be a list of requires, but needs to have these lines as well:

```
(devcards.core/start-devcard-ui!)

(defn refresh []
  (println "In cards.card-ui that starts the ui"))
```

The `:cards` build in `shadow-cljs.edn` becomes a bit simpler:

```
      :cards {:target           :browser
              :output-dir       "resources/public/js/cards"
              :asset-path       "js/cards"
              :compiler-options {:devcards true}
              :modules          {:main
                                 {:entries [cards.card-ui]}}
              :devtools         {:after-load cards.card-ui/refresh
                                 :http-root "resources/public"
                                 :http-port 3450}
              }
```

Another thing I had wrong was the HTML (`cards.html`). Here is just the `body` tag of the markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="js/cards/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Some import pointers from the Devcards site: https://github.com/bhauman/devcards#usage-without-figwheel

The lein template project: https://github.com/fulcrologic/fulcro-lein-template